# Ionic & Angular JS: trying to add item to list but list is not defined

Tags: angularjs, list, ionic-framework

I've checked various threads and tutorials, simply trying to add an item to an ionic list by clicking on a button. However, I'm not able to make it.
I'm pretty sure that I'm the problem.. :)

Please find my code below. Assigning a date to newDate works fine, and the array groups works fine to create a list (via ng-repeat). The problem occurs when I'm trying to run the function addEntry via a button, no item is added to the list and I'm receiving "Error: groups is not defined" in the console log.

I hope that it's a simple declaration problem which can be solved by a one sentence answer... thanks in advance!!!

HTML Button:

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="doRefresh()" ui-sref="menu.tagebucheintrag">
Send
</button>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.groups = [{name:'25.11.2016'},{name:'26.11.2016'},{name:'27.11.2016'},{name:'28.11.2016'}];

$scope.addEntry = function () {     
    console.log('Button pressed');
    var newDate = FromDate
    console.log(newDate);
    $scope.groups.push({ name: newDate });
    console.log(groups[0])
};
```

Comment: What is `fromDate`?

Comment: fromDate is the current date as string. But this is fine, console.log(newDate); provides me "2017-01-08".

Comment: How did you get that? did you define it somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 1):

On clicking button you are calling `doRefresh()` but there is no refresh function. You have to change `ng-click="doRefresh()"` to `ng-click="addEntry()"` to push the date if `fromDate` is works.

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="addEntry()" ui-sref="menu.tagebucheintrag">
Send
</button>
```

Otherwise do this

```
$scope.groups = [{name:'25.11.2016'},{name:'26.11.2016'},{name:'27.11.2016'},{name:'28.11.2016'}];
$scope.addEntry= function(){
     $scope.newDate = new Date().getDate() + '.' + (new Date().getMonth()+1) + '.' + new Date().getFullYear();
     $scope.groups.push({ name: newDate });
}
```

Comment: Oh, classy. I renamed it half way through. Thanks for the hint, but the problem remains...

Comment: Yes, I'm still receiving the error that groups is not defined.. do I have to declare groups different in case I want to use it in a function?

Comment: I thought you were added `$scope.groups` in your code. Now, see the updated answe

Comment: Yes, sure, as it is shown in the initial post. Thanks for the on going support :D I've added $scope.groups to declare it, but I was wondering whether I have to mark it as global or what not to use it in the function addEntry